# Methods of characteristics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The function $u(x, t)$ satisfies $\frac{du}{dt} $ + $\frac{du}{dx}$ = $0$ in $x > 0, t > 0$

Subject to the initial conditions $u(x, 0) = sin(x)$, $x > 0$ and the boundary condition $u(0, t) = sin(t)$, $t > 0.$

Determine the values of $u$ in the whole of the quarterplane $x > 0, t > 0$

What i did:

$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1$ -------> t = s + a, but $t=0$ means $s=o$ so $t=s$

$\frac{dx}{ds} = 1$ -------> $x = s + b$ subject to $x(0) = \xi $. This leads to $\xi = x - t$

$\frac{du}{ds} = 0$ -------> $u(s)= c = f(\xi)$  = $f(x-t)$ = $u(x,t)$

Then using the inital condition:

$u(x,0) = f(x) = sin(x) $

Now of course when i use the boundary condition it doesn't make sense :/

So i was just wondering where i went wrong and if my general technique is right?

Many thanks!

Comment: The "characteristics" here are a family of parallel straight lines on each of which $u (x,t)$ is a constant determined by its intercept with the initial conditions $u (x,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general technique is correct - the equation $u_t + u_x = 0$ means that $u$ is constant along the characteristic curves $x-t = \mathrm{const}$. In other words, $u(x,t) = f(x-t)$ for some function $f$.

As far as I understand, you only consider the characteristic curves starting at points $(0,x)$ with $x>0$. This is of course not sufficient, as it only determines $f$ for positive arguments and $u$ in the region $\{ (x,t): 0 < t < x \}$.

If you also consider starting points $(t,0)$ with $t>0$, you end up with $u(x,t) = \sin(|x-t|)$. This is not a $C^1$ function (only Lipschitz), but it satisfies the equation in the weak sense.

Note that in this case, the distinction between *initial conditions* and *boundary conditions* is immaterial - variables $x$ and $t$ play exactly the same role.